# Shannon's proof of the entropy power inequality

Tags: reference-request, it.information-theory, calculus-of-variations, entropy, isoperimetric-problems

In Shannon's paper on information theory, [found here,](http://worrydream.com/refs/Shannon%20-%20A%20Mathematical%20Theory%20of%20Communication.pdf) he asserts the [entropy power inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_power_inequality) in appendix 6, found on page 52. I was reading his proof and it seems like there is a gap. Through his method, I believe one can only conclude that the Gaussian is a local minimum for his calculus of variations problem, rather than a global minimum.

Since then, has anyone been able to fill in the gap of Shannon's proof? I am aware that there are other proofs of the inequality, but would like to know if someone was able to use his methods to show the Gaussian is a global minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Amir Dembo, Thomas Cover and Joy Thomas talk about (and prove) entropy power inequality towards the end of this paper in two different ways:

- http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~cover/papers/dembo_cover_thomas_91.pdf

Liyao Wang and Mokshay Madiman prove Entropy-Power inequality using

- http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mm888/Pubs/2013/ISIT-rearrange13.pdf

Olivier Rioul proves using mutual information

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0701050.pdf

---

Any of these three proofs - while probably legit - risk the same gaps as you are indicating.  Of these I recommend Dembo-Cover-Thomas since they offer a fairly complete discussion of entropy inqualites, including their connection to Brunn-Minkowski

- ["Entropy" proof of Brunn-Minkowski Inequality?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167951/entropy-proof-of-brunn-minkowski-inequality)

Entropy is $h(X) = \log \# \{\text{microstates}\}$ and entropy power of (vector-valued) random variable: $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $N(X)  = e^{\frac{1}{n}h(X)}$ so this is counting the $n$-th root of the number of microstates.

Shannon's definition of entropy power involves an integral over frequency space, and he may have been dealing with time dependent signals $x(t)$ instead of random variables $X$.  Since he says that [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) $x(t) = W(t)$ maximizes entropy power.  Classically the notion of "power" as work / time makes sense here.  Then he uses ergodicity to approximate $x(t)$ by its average distribution $ \langle x(t) \rangle = X$.

#### Statement of Entropy Power Inequality

Let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector-valued random variable.  It has a probability density over $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$h(X) = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} dx\; p(x) \log p(x) = \# \{ \text{ microstates } \}$$

I speculate Shannon's notion of Entropy Power (of a probability distribution) is related to the notion of [power spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density) (of a time series) in signal processing but I can't write an exact derivation.

$$ e^{\frac{2}{n}h(X)}+ e^{\frac{2}{n}h(Y)} \leq e^{\frac{2}{n}h(X+Y)}$$

#### Proof of Entropy Power Inequlaity

You really have to stick to your guns here that entropy log-counts the number of microstates.  The formal result is called the

- Law of Large Numbers
- Asymptotic Equidistribution Property

Using LLN or AEP we can say although $X$ ranges over all $\mathbb{R}^n$, *usually* $X$ stays in the "weakly typical set" or "strongly typical set".

Using **Brunn-Minkowski** inequality we can say the weak/strong typical sets of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ combine to get the volume of $X+Y$.

$$ \mathrm{Vol}(X)^{2/n} + \mathrm{Vol}(Y)^{2/n} \leq \mathrm{Vol}(X \stackrel{E}{+} Y)^{2/n}$$

where $\stackrel{E}{+}$ is a variant of Minkowski sum $ X \stackrel{E}{+} Y = \{ x + y: (x,y) \in E \} $

Comment: hopefully I can work through one or more of these when I get back from the dentist!